# Primefaces - dynamic menubar with lazy menuitem loading

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lazy-initialization

I'm moving legacy system to Java-stack. UI of this system have large count of pages with tree hierarchy. For navigation I've used p:menubar. When user logging on menubar is filling. Request all from DB takes much time so I want have lazy initialization for menubar subitems (and for subitems of it's subitems). Is it possible?

Comment: Have you read about **Dynamic Menus** in the Primefaces's documentation?
You can create the menu programatically, so you can load step by step all you want. For example, when you click in a menu element, with ajax (and `update`), your app can load the submenu. This is the documentation for [latest version](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf)

Comment: [Here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml) is the online documentation with an example. The example uses a simple menu but you can use for a menubar too.

Comment: @Miguel so you suggest write code wich changes menuItem to submenu and load data for it when user click on menuitem? Wanted out-of-the-box solution, not this bicycle :-(

Comment: sorry but `p:menubar` doesn't have any attribute for lazy load of menu items and I don't know other easier solution. If you need lazy load you have to develop by yourself. Maybe other person can help you better than me.